# Why is a difference between javascript focus and force state focus from google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why when I use `element.focus()` on an HTML section the outline doesn't appear but if I force the state from Chrome developer tools the outline appears?

[image: force state from Chrome developer tools]

**Later edit:**
I discovered that Chrome shows outline on focus elements which have contenteditable=true